# Windows CMD batch 'if' statement string check works sometimes with case-sensitivity

Tags: windows, batch-file, if-statement, cmd, case-sensitive

I have a simple CMD 'if' check:

```
set param=%9
IF %param%=="true" ( 
...
```

param is coming from Python and is a Boolean which can be `True` or `False` and which `str` converted version is again starting with upper-case: `"True"` or `"False"`
The problem here is when I run mentioned CMD script as Windows batch file on my PC, it works, despite the case difference and absence of quotes, but on other PC it works only if I add quotes and write uppercase "`True"`:

```
IF "%param%"=="True" (
```

The only difference I can find on my and the other PC is that my Windows language is English and other one uses German. Both use Windows 10.

What can cause the CMD to work differently?

Comment: If  /I to remove case of sensitivity

Comment: @T3RR0R - That's not the question. They're saying that it shouldn't work but it does and they want to know why.

Comment: Also, Set "param=%~9"

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that the input you are getting from your python script is somehow different on the two machines.

Comment: It may not be the way the question is phrased, however it's likely to be the solution to the issue

Comment: @T3RR0R not at all a solution to the issue. The OP is specifically stating that it is working when it should not be working. In other words he does not want to match it case insensitive at all, hence the question. @Serob. Please show what the result is before the if statement when you do `echo %param%` I however suscpect that on the system with the related issue, `%9` is already coming in double quote and in lower case.. I need you do do the echo so we can confirm. so please either do `echo %9` or `echo %param%`

Comment: Try debugging your script using `echo %*` and `IF "%param%"=="True" ( echo ["%param%"=="True"] ) else ( echo ["%param%"##"True"] )`.

Answer (score 0):

---

So, why not use **`findstr`** instead **`if`**:

With **`findstr`** will check if argument/parameter **`%~9`** match with string **True/False**, and take action accorded results.

```
@echo off 

echo/%~9|%__APPDIR__%Findstr "True False" >nul && (
if "%%~9"=="True" (set "_str=True") else set "_str=%%~9")
if not "%_str%"=="" echo/%_str% = %~9
```

- Input with 9th arguments and then results

  ---

```
Q59717331.cmd 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 True
rem :: results ::
%~9 = True

Q59717331.cmd 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 False
rem :: results ::
%~9 = False

Q59717331.cmd 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 TRUE
rem :: results (no results/no match::

Q59717331.cmd 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 FALSE
rem :: results (no results/no match::

Q59717331.cmd 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 true
rem :: results (no results/no match::

Q59717331.cmd 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 false
rem :: results (no results/no match::
```